# Why is "Evaluatable" unchecked by default in cell option but cell still execute?

Tags: front-end, options, cells

In my Mathematica, all my cells have the option "Evaluatable" unchecked by default
[image]

Thus, if I want to prevent some cells to be executed, it is not possible because Evaluatable is already unchecked (but cells are still executed).

Why is it so ? Is it a strange comportment with my mathematica or there is something I misunderstood ?

[edit]

As the comment from @b3m2a1 suggested, this is what there is in the cell when I open it with SHIFT CTRL E :

```
    In[128]:= Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{"1", "+", "1"}]], "Input",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.706802150710745*^9, 3.7068021512522154`*^9}}]

Out[128]= Cell[BoxData["2"], "Output",
 CellChangeTimes->{3.706802151784894*^9}]
```

I just wrote the code 1+1 and pressed enter (all of my cells have evaluatable unchecked so I wrote the simplest code to show it).

Comment: Would you mind going to one of the cells where `Evaluatable` is supposed to be false, opening the cell expression via Shift-Ctrl-E, and copying everything that's in there into a code block in your question? That would, I think, help people understand what's going on.

Comment: I edited. Thanks !

Comment: So it seems `Evaluatable` *hasn't* been set to false. I bet the lack of check mark is showing that some are evaluatable and some aren't. Must be interfering with something. Try going to Format > Edit Stylesheet... and adding `Cell[StyleData[All],Evaluatable->False]` to it.

Comment: What does `CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Input", Evaluatable}]` return?

Comment: CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Input", Evaluatable}] returns True

Comment: If I select Input cell bracket the `Evaluatable` in menu is checked.

Comment: Hmmm so you think my problem is probably a bug ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't completely clear, but I suppose that you are confused by the fact that `"Output"` cells have `Evaluatable -> False` but despite this they can be evaluated when you put the cursor inside such a cell and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Output", Evaluatable}]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

The reason is that such cells are auto-converted into `"Input"` cells when you edit them. But when you select the `"Output"` cell bracket and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> nothing happens because you haven't edited the cell and it has `Evaluatable -> False`.

Comment: Aaaaaah you are right !! In fact the input line has Evaluatable true but not the whole bracket which contains the input and the output !! I used to select the whole stuff. In fact I want to disable execution of a large part of code. Do you know if there is a way of selecting ONLY input cells in a huge bracket ? Because I would like to disable the evaluatable option on the inputs only

Comment: Well in fact If i click on evaluatable a first time, it will make the output evaluatable as the input already is. If I click a second time it will make unevaluatable both. But I would like to only apply this option on the input parts (so I need to select only input of my big bracket)

Comment: I'm glad that my guess is right. :) This probably can be done with a custom Palette. I don't think this is possible using only FrontEnd's menu items.

Comment: Ok ok thank you. Yes well done you had the good intuition ;)